# How to open android application through a link in facebook post?

Tags: android, facebook

We are developing an android application which is posting a message on facebook using facebook connect. The message contains a link.

We would like to open the android application if a user click on the link posted on facebook.

Here are the steps:

[1] Consider a mobile with facebook app installed

[2] Install our application as well on the same mobile

[3] Post message on facebook with a link using our application

[4] Go to facebook application

[5] Click on the link and it should open our application.

Actually we don't want to use , other than that is it possible to customize/format the link by passing 'facebook application id' or 'application package name' as query string parameters?

Please let us your views...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html), or this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2958870/1589566

For some cases, you need to add these too.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
```